# automatize path directory in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I build an automatic program that needs the user to modify only few parameters in the Launch file.

I ask myself if it's possible to automatize the file path automation according to the custom "year" and "month" ?

**Structure**

```
 Launch.r
     | Import.r   #(load librairies and call specific programs)
           | Topic1.r
                |.......
           | Topic2.r
     ......
```

```
    #-- > Launch file
    
    # Parameters to be personalized by the user  
    year <-  2021
    month <- 01
    
    
    # File directory
    import <- c('c:/folderX/year/month/folder')
    export <- c('c:/folderX/year/export/folder1')
    
    
    .....
```

When I run the program, R sort

```
import    "c:/folderX/year/month/folder"
export    "c:/folderX/year/export/folder1"
```

My goal is to get

```
  import  "c:/folderX/2021/01/folder"
  export  "c:/folderX/2021/export/folder1"
```

Would you have tips to help me?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question correctly, `file.path` can accept variables as parts of the path e.g.

```
year <-  2021
month <- 01
import <- file.path("c:/folderX", year, month, "folder")
```

should give

```
#> [1] "c:/folderX/2021/1/folder"
```

Comment: And if you want the current year or month use `format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")` and `format(Sys.Date(), "%m")`, so `file.path("c:/folderX", format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"), format(Sys.Date(), "%m"), "folder")` would do the trick.

Comment: That's neat - I thought you had to go around with `paste` to create the path. Also a reminder that `normalizePath` exists (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/normalizePath)

Comment: Thank you for your contributions. I find them very interesting.
To stay in the logic / structure of my programming I'll integrate Ovid's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `glue` package for string generation from templates:

```
# Parameters to be personalized by the user  
library(glue)
year <-  2021
month <- 01


# File directory
import <- glue(
  'c:/folderX/{year}/{month}/folder', 
  month = sprintf('%02d', month), 
  year = year
)

export <- glue(
  'c:/folderX/{year}/{month}/folder1', 
  month = sprintf('%02d', month), 
  year = year
)

# glue can also take variables from environment:
export <- glue(
  'c:/folderX/{year}/{month}/folder1'
)
# in this case just make sure that month variable is a string in correct format
```